# Webapp2 Route regular expression for serving blobs

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to serve blobs, am using Webapp2. I've followed the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview

However, I get a 404 error when accessing something like `/serve/5VxklPAO0WRbnRtVcb7SJA==`

I never get to the ServeHandler. I believe this is because the regex I have in the Webapp2 route doesn't match what comes after the serve/ part of the URL. This is what I have in the main.py file:
`webapp2.Route(r'/serve/([^/]+)?', 'ServeHandler')`

If I remove the blob key and the corresponding regex from the Webapp2 route, I hit my ServeHandler.

Thanks for any regex help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/serve/<:([^/]+)?>', handler=ServeHandler),           # helper to process upload
```